# How to use bazel to build the AGP source code

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, bazel, android-source

I Downloaded AGP source code from [here](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/download#installing-repo) and follow [these](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/bazel/README.md) instructions, but now when I try to build the source code or run tests i face following error

this is my branch "studio-master-dev"

```
bazel test //tools/base/...
 fetching local_repository rule //external:blaze: java.io.IOException: The repository's path is "tools/vendor/google3/blaze" (absolute: "/Users/username/studio-master-dev/tools/vendor/google3/blaze") but it does not exist or is not a directory.
```

I checked the path and error is right the folder doesn't exist but How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning at the top of the instructions the OP links to says that it does not work outside of Google:

> Warning: This does not currently work for AOSP Issue 126764883. The required binaries are checked in as prebuilts, so you can run tests using Intellij (tools/base and tools/idea projects), Ant (Studio only) and Gradle (Build system and command line tools).

Comment: oops missed it, thanks